# If $p$ is prime and $p\equiv 3 \pmod 5$, show that for every $a$, $x^5\equiv a \pmod p$ is solvable.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I tried all sort of things. I know it is supposed to be easy but I can't seem to be thinking anymore. I could really use even the most basic lead here. 
I tried working with primitive roots and quadratic residue but nothing seems to do any process. I find no point in elaborating a certain way for I have few ways started, none of which leads anywhere.

Comment: Hint: Since $5|(p-3)$ we know that $5$ does not divide $p-1$.  Hence there are no elements of order $5$ $mod(p)$.  But if we ever had a non-trivial solution of $x^5\equiv y^5\;mod(p)$ then $(xy^{-1})^5\equiv 1$.

Comment: That just what I wrote! 
I didn't however arrive at the last result. How did I not see it????

Comment: Can it be that direct, though?
Am I to explain some things all the way to $(xy^{-1})^5\equiv 1$? I mean, special, non-obvious notes?

Comment: Well...I'd handle the case of $a\equiv 0$ separately, just on general principles.  Then I'd mention that, by the Pigeonhole Principle, if we we let $X$ run through the non-zero residues $mod(p)$ then either {$X^5$} covers all the non-zero residues or it hits one of them (at least) twice.  That's enough.

Comment: For the record, you should say $p$ is prime (so that $y$ must have an inverse in Lulu's argument). Modulo $8$, the only $5$th powers are $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @RobArthan  Absolutely correct, as to $p$ needing to be a prime.    The remark about $8$, however, is wrong...$3^5\equiv 3 \;mod(8)$.  But you certainly can't solve $x^5\equiv 2 \;mod(8)$.

Comment: @Lulu: yes, you are right: what I should have said was that modulo 8, $x^4$ (not $x^5$)  is $0$ or $1$ according as $x$ is even or odd, so that non-zero even numbers are not $5$th powers. I've edited the question to say $p$ is prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, the result is obvious. So suppose that $a$ is not divisible by $p$.

Note that $p-1$ and $5$ are relatively prime. So there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $5x+(p-1)y=1$. By choosing the signs of $x$ and $y$ suitably, we conclude that there are positive integers $s$ and $t$ such that $5s=(p-1)t+1$. Thus 
$$a^{(p-1)t+1}=a^{5s}=(a^s)^5.\tag{1}$$
But
$$a^{(p-1)t +1}=a\cdot (a^{p-1})^t \equiv a\pmod{p}\tag{2}.$$
From (1) and (2) we conclude that $(a^s)^5\equiv a\pmod{p}$.

Comment: $s$ and $t$ do not have to be positive, as $a$ is not divisible by $p.$

Comment: Naturally they do not **have to be** positive. But they can be chosen to be positive. One could also work directly with the $x$ and $y$ of the answer, but that has the technical disadvantage that one have to  introduce inverses.